# Does this patent cover up the use of a chuck to screw on to a threaded pipe

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [US8567823](https://www.google.com/patents/US8567823)

Does the patent block the use of chucks on threaded tubes?, my design uses a rotating wheel to screw the chuck on which is locked at the end

Comment: I changed the link from the application US20100244435 to the subsequent issued patent US8567823.

Comment: Can you define the term "chuck"?